# Automatically extracting SMILES of sub-group of larger SMILES structure?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, databases, fats, lipids

Is there any software tool that can automatically extract SMILES of fatty acid legs of phospholipids if the SMILES of the parent lipid is given? Or any tool that can do it in InChI ?

Any advice will be really appreciated.